# Python 3.x replacements with Unicode characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode

I want to replace line feeds by spaces when the next line begins with a lowercase character.

My code for Python 3.3 is working when the next line begins with [a-z] but fails if it begins with a (lowercase) Unicode character.

```
Test file (saved as UTF-8): Test to check<CRLF>whether it's working.<CRLF>Aquela é<CRLF>árvore pequena.<CRLF>

import os
input_file = 'test.txt'
input_file_path = os.path.join("c:", "\\", "Users", "Paulo", "workspace", "pdf_to_text", input_file)
input_string = open(input_file_path).read()

print(input_string)
import re

pattern = r'\n([a-zàáâãäåæçčèéêëěìíîïłðñńòóôõöøőřśŝšùúûüůýÿżžÞ]+)'
pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern)
replacement_string = " \\1"
output_string = pattern_obj.sub(replacement_string, input_string)
print(output_string)`
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the test file?

Comment: What are those extra `""` supposed to be doing on the `pattern =` line?

Comment: Also, why are you hardcoding this specific subset of lowercase letters instead of either using the Unicode character category `Ll` or the appropriate locale notion?

Comment: Most importantly: can you give us some sample input data? The simplest way to do that is to give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has `input_string = "<some constant that demonstrates the problem>"` in place of the code to load it from a file we don't have.

Comment: Also, are you sure your text editor saved this source code as UTF-8 rather than some other encoding? You're on Windows, and many Windows editors default to something different.

Comment: (Newbie question): Could not find how to use character category L1 - that's why I added all lowercase chars of interest.

Comment: Don't put relevant info in the comments; [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/RNw8lP

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I checked and it really works if input is a string (not a string from a file). Problem seems to be related to file reading and writing.

Comment: @pstrg do a `print(repr(input_string.encode('utf-8')))` on a line that fails and tell us what it comes back with. I think J.F. Sebastian is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... The unicode characters é and á in the original file are changed to Ã© and Ã¡ respectively when I read() the file.

Your actual issue is unrelated to regexes. You are reading utf-8 text using latin-1 encoding that is incorrect.

```
>>> print("é".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))
Ã©
>>> print("á".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))
Ã¡
```

To read utf-8 file:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.read()
```

#### Old answer about regexes (unrelated to OPs issue):

In general, a single user-perceived character such as `ç`, `é` may span multiple Unicode codepoints therefore `[çé]` may match these Unicode codepoints separately instead of matching the whole character. `(?:ç|é)` would fix this one issue, there are others e.g., Unicode normalization (NFC, NFKD).

> I want to replace line feeds by spaces when the next line begins with a lowercase character.

`regex` module supports POSIX character class `[:lower:]`:

```
import regex # $ pip install regex

text = ("Test to check\n"
        "whether it's working.\n"
        "Aquela \xe9\n"
        "\xe1rvore pequena.\n")
print(text)
# -> Test to check
# -> whether it's working.
# -> Aquela é
# -> árvore pequena.
print(regex.sub(r'\n(?=[[:lower:]])', ' ', text))
# -> Test to check whether it's working.
# -> Aquela é árvore pequena.
```

To emulate `[:lower:]` class using `re` module:

```
import re
import sys
import unicodedata

# \p{Ll} chars
lower_chars = [u for u in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode)) 
               if unicodedata.category(u) == 'Ll']
lower = "|".join(map(re.escape, lower_chars))
print(re.sub(r"\n(?={lower})".format(lower=lower), ' ', text))
```

The result is the same.